# How do I resolve 'WebElement' missing in a script

Tags: qwebelement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OET4.png)

Can someone help me to resolve this error emssage please? I am new to this so aplogies in advance if too basic question.

The error says 'move_to' requires webElement and my webElement is 'institution'.
Perphaps my script on institution is not right...

Thank you. SJ